# My sqs queue is sending a s3:TestEvent every few minutes to my lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda set to trigger via sqs on bucket updates. Usually I see a test event when the lambda is first launched, but now I'm receiving them at regular intervals, every few minutes. What could be causing this?

Here is the printed event:

```
{"Records": [{"messageId": "removed", 
"receiptHandle": "removed", 
"body": "{"Service":"Amazon S3",
        "Event":"s3:TestEvent",
        "Time":"2023-01-11T06:57:48.718Z",
        "Bucket":"my-bucket-xslypc1",
        "RequestId":"removed",
        "HostId":"removed"}", 
        "attributes": {"ApproximateReceiveCount": "3", 
        "SentTimestamp": "1673420268744", 
        "SenderId": "removed", 
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1673420268751"}, 
"messageAttributes": {}, "md5OfBody": "removed", "eventSource": "aws:sqs", "eventSourceARN": 
"arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:ACCT:MyQueue-OlY2Ge6bFxnd", "awsRegion": "us-west-2"}]
```

thanks

Comment: This test event is generated by AWS S3 to make sure the proper permission is in place. Are you able to properly consume the message?

Comment: No it currently fails as I have not set up anything to handle that test event. Is this why it keeps retrying? Is there documentation on how I should handle this? "When the notification is first enabled, an s3:TestEvent occurs. ". But this is hitting me every 2-3 minutes

Comment: Yes that's why. There should be a timeout on your sqs message, or DLQ. When it cannot be processed a numerous amount of time, then it goes to DLQ. In the meantime, you can manually go into the queue, find the testEvent and delete it.

Comment: thanks! it does say one message in flight, so I'm guessing it's that bouncing around. Fairly new to SQS but will look in to manually deleting as well as DLQ/timeout